# unable to unregister this item an error occurred

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, crm

I have troble unregistering my plugin. "unable to unregister this item an error occurred".
I am using p![enter image description here][1]lugin Registration Tool version 5.0.9690.3739.

---

```
Unhandled Exception: system.Service model.FaultException 1[[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault, Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]: The 'Delete' operation on the current component(name='SdkMessageProcessingStep', id='726aaafe-adce-e211-8dc2-000c293f67e0') failed during managed property evaluation of condition: 'Microsoft.Crm.BusinessEntities.IsComponentDeletionEnabledCondition'
```

Detail: 
     -2147160014
  
    
      0
      SdkMessageProcessingStep
    
    
      1
      726aaafe-adce-e211-8dc2-000c293f67e0
    
    
      2
      Delete

========================================================================

???

Answer (score 1):

The error says that the plugin step is a managed plugin step. You cannot delete this one by the PluginRegistrationTool. If you want to delete the plugin step, you must delete the whole managed solution via the UI of CRM. But that's not wat you want, I think....